# OnUnbind of Accessibility Service is not called

Tags: android, accessibilityservice

I have created one Accessibility Service but if I switch off the accessibility service(for my app) from settings panel, and the app is not alive, `onUnbind` of service is not called. `onUnbind` is called everytime if app is alive.

```
07-13 11:47:24.327 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getSystemService, referenced from method service.MyAccessibilityService.access$super
07-13 11:47:24.327 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 502: Landroid/content/Context;.getSystemService (Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
07-13 11:47:24.329 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0035
07-13 11:47:24.329 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.getColorStateList, referenced from method service.MyAccessibilityService.access$super
07-13 11:47:24.330 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 484: Landroid/content/Context;.getColorStateList (I)Landroid/content/res/ColorStateList;
07-13 11:47:24.331 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x004f
07-13 11:47:24.331 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityService.getWindows, referenced from method service.MyAccessibilityService.access$super
07-13 11:47:24.332 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 25: Landroid/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityService;.getWindows ()Ljava/util/List;
07-13 11:47:24.333 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0080
07-13 11:47:24.333 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.getCodeCacheDir, referenced from method service.MyAccessibilityService.access$super
07-13 11:47:24.334 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 555: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.getCodeCacheDir ()Ljava/io/File;
07-13 11:47:24.335 10974-10974/com.example.tarun.myappforkeyevent D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x00e6
```

Why is it showing these errors instead of calling `onUnbind`?

Comment: the above scenario is happening in case app is **not alive**.